# Hbase loading .opv and .ope give hexadecimal output

Tags: java, oracle, hbase, graph-databases, cloudera

I'm using Oracle Big Data Spatial & Graph v.2.5 and following [the official guide to load through Java a Graph on HBase](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/property-graph/21.1/spgdg/using-property-graphs-oracle-database.html#GUID-40B77BBF-9FEC-412A-8A3F-8DB41993E4C7).
This is my code:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] arg) throws Exception {
        org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator.configure();
        OraclePropertyGraphDataLoader opgdl = OraclePropertyGraphDataLoader.getInstance();
        String vfile = "/root/oracle_property_files/connections.opv";
        String efile = "/root/oracle_property_files/connections.ope";
        PgHbaseGraphConfig cfg = GraphConfigBuilder.forPropertyGraphHbase()
                .setName("config").setZkQuorum("zk01node,zk02node,zk03node").build();
        OraclePropertyGraph opg = OraclePropertyGraph.getInstance(cfg);
        opgdl.loadData(opg, vfile, efile, 48);
    }
}
```

Using this libraries:

[image: libraries]

This is my .opv file:

```
1,name,1,Alice,,
1,age,2,,31,
2,name,1,Bob,,
2,age,2,,27,
```

And this is my .ope file:

```
1,1,2,knows,type,1,friends,,
```

My code creates on HBase the tables: configEI.
configGE.
configIT.
configVI.
configVT.

The problem is that if I launch the command `scan 'configVT.'` The output is mixed in hexadecimal and ASCII values:

```
hbase(main):003:0> scan 'configVT.'
ROW                                                  COLUMN+CELL
 3v\x93ur|\xD7\xD3\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02   column=v:i\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01, timestamp=1624009988902, value=knows
 3v\x93ur|\xD7\xD3\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02   column=v:kage, timestamp=1624009989001, value=\x00\x00\x00\x1B\x02
 3v\x93ur|\xD7\xD3\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02   column=v:kname, timestamp=1624009989001, value=Bob\x01
 \xCB\xFC%\xA7qt\x02\x84\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00 column=v:kage, timestamp=1624009988909, value=\x00\x00\x00\x1F\x02
 \x01
 \xCB\xFC%\xA7qt\x02\x84\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00 column=v:kname, timestamp=1624009988909, value=Alice\x01
 \x01
 \xCB\xFC%\xA7qt\x02\x84\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00 column=v:o\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01, timestamp=1624009988909, value=knows
 \x01
2 row(s) in 0.0490 seconds
```

I would like to have a more readable result.

Edit: It seems that String and Date types are stored correctly (but with some HEX escape character as `Alice\x01`). Instead the integers are totally converted to theirs HEX values.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Using the `scan` command, i read the tables as simply hbase tables, but they aren't, they are Oracle Big Data Spatial & Graph tables stored in hbase. So my `configVT.` table is only one of the five tables created with the java method `opgdl.loadData` and reading just it is not enough.
In order to get readable result, I should read it has edges or vertex:

```
opg.getVertices().forEach( e -> {
    System.out.println("id vertex: " + e.getId());
    e.getPropertyKeys().forEach(p -> {
        System.out.println("property: " + p);
        System.out.println("value: " + e.getProperty(p));
    });
});

opg.getEdges().forEach( e -> {
    System.out.println("label: " + e.getLabel());
    System.out.println("id edge: " + e.getId());
    Vertex vIn = e.getVertex(Direction.IN);
    Vertex vOut = e.getVertex(Direction.OUT);
    System.out.println("edge from: " + vOut.getId());
    System.out.println("edge to: " + vIn.getId());
    e.getPropertyKeys().forEach(p -> {
        System.out.println("property: " + p);
        System.out.println("value: " + e.getProperty(p));
    });
});
```